# Only updating half the data to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is for updating data in a MySQL table. It was written by pulling all the data from one query but I have tried to adapt it to pull data from two queries to improve the ordering. Now only some of the records update when the submit button is clicked and I'm not sure how to fix it.

The original code was:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $total = $_POST['total'];
        $park_id = $_POST['park_id'];
        if($password=="****"){

        for($i =1; $i<=$total; $i++){
            $ride_id = $_POST['ride_id'.$i];
            $name = $_POST['ride_name'.$i];
            $type = $_POST['type'.$i];
            $topride = $_POST['topride'.$i];
            $info = $_POST['info'.$i];
            $speed = $_POST['speed'.$i];
            $height = $_POST['height'.$i];
            $length = $_POST['length'.$i];
            $inversions = $_POST['inversions'.$i];
        $query = "update tpf_rides set name='$name',type='$type'";
        if($topride!=""){$query .= ",top_ride=$topride";}
        if($info!=""){$query .= ",info='$info'";}
        if($height!=""){$query .= ",height=$height";}
        if($length!=""){$query .= ",length=$length";}
        if($speed!=""){$query .= ",speed=$speed";}
        if($inversions!=""){$query .= ",inversions=$inversions";}
    $query .= " where ride_id=".$ride_id." and park_id=".$park_id;  
            mysql_query($query);
        }
        header('location:index.php?msg=Successfully Updated.');
        }else{
            echo "Enter Correct Password.";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "select name from tpf_parks where park_id=".$id;
        $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
        echo '<h2>'.$result['name'].'</h2>';
        $qry = "select * from tpf_rides where park_id=".$id;
        $res = mysql_query($qry);
        $no = mysql_num_rows($res);
        $x = 0;
        if($no>0){ ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$no?>" name="total">
         <input type="hidden" value="<?=$id?>" name="park_id">
        <table> <?php
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ $x++;
                echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['ride_id'].'" name="ride_id'.$x.'">';
                    echo '<tr><td>Name : </td><td><input type="text" name="ride_name'.$x.'" value="'.$row['name'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Type : </td><td><input type="text" name="type'.$x.'" value="'.$row['type'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Top Ride : </td><td><input type="text" name="topride'.$x.'" value="'.$row['top_ride'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Info : </td><td><input type="text" name="info'.$x.'" value="'.$row['info'].'"></td></tr>';

                    if($row['type']!="Roller Coaster"){
                    echo '<tr><td>Speed : </td><td><input type="text" name="speed'.$x.'" value="'.$row['speed'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Height : </td><td><input type="text" name="height'.$x.'" value="'.$row['height'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Length : </td><td><input type="text" name="length'.$x.'" value="'.$row['length'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Inversions : </td><td><input type="text" name="inversions'.$x.'" value="'.$row['inversions'].'"></td></tr>';
                    }
                    echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>';
                } ?>
                    <tr><td>Password :</td><td><input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input onclick="return check()" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"></td></tr>

                </table>
               </form>
                <?php
            }else{
                echo "No Rides in this park.";
            }
    }else{
        if(isset($_GET['msg'])){echo $_GET['msg'].'<br>';}
        $qry = "select * from  tpf_parks order by name";
        $res = mysql_query($qry);
        ?>
        Select Park : <select name="park" onChange="getdata(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option value="">Select Park</option>
        <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$row['park_id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></option>
        <?  } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

and the new code where I altered the queries is here:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $total = $_POST['total'];
        $park_id = $_POST['park_id'];
        if($password=="*****"){

        for($i =1; $i<=$total; $i++){
            $ride_id = $_POST['ride_id'.$i];
            $name = $_POST['ride_name'.$i];
            $type = $_POST['type'.$i];
            $topride = $_POST['topride'.$i];
            $info = $_POST['info'.$i];
            $speed = $_POST['speed'.$i];
            $height = $_POST['height'.$i];
            $length = $_POST['length'.$i];
            $inversions = $_POST['inversions'.$i];

        $query = "update tpf_rides set name='$name',type='$type'";
        if($topride!=""){$query .= ",top_ride=$topride";}
        $query .= ",info='$info'";
        if($height!=""){$query .= ",height=$height";}
        if($length!=""){$query .= ",length=$length";}
        if($speed!=""){$query .= ",speed=$speed";}
        if($inversions!=""){$query .= ",inversions=$inversions";}
    $query .= " where ride_id=".$ride_id." and park_id=".$park_id;  
            mysql_query($query);
        }
        header('location:index.php?msg=Successfully Updated.');
        }else{
            echo "Enter Correct Password.";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "select name from tpf_parks where park_id=".$id;
        $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
        echo '<h2>'.$result['name'].'</h2>';
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM  tpf_rides
WHERE park_id = $id AND type LIKE '%Roller Coaster%' ORDER BY name ASC";
        $res = mysql_query($qry);


        $qry2 = "SELECT * FROM  tpf_rides
WHERE park_id = $id AND type NOT LIKE '%Roller Coaster%' ORDER BY name ASC";
        $res2 = mysql_query($qry2);

        $qry3 = "SELECT * FROM  tpf_rides WHERE park_id = $id";
        $res3 = mysql_query($qry2);

        $no = mysql_num_rows($res3);
        $x = 0;
        $xx = 0;
        if($no>0){ ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$no?>" name="total">
         <input type="hidden" value="<?=$id?>" name="park_id">
        <table> <?php

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ $x++;
                echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['ride_id'].'" name="ride_id'.$x.'">';
                    echo '<tr><td>Name : </td><td><input type="text" name="ride_name'.$x.'" value="'.$row['name'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Type : </td><td><input type="text" name="type'.$x.'" value="'.$row['type'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Top Ride : </td><td><input type="text" name="topride'.$x.'" value="'.$row['top_ride'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Info : </td><td><input type="text" name="info'.$x.'" value="'.$row['info'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Speed : </td><td><input type="text" name="speed'.$x.'" value="'.$row['speed'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Height : </td><td><input type="text" name="height'.$x.'" value="'.$row['height'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Length : </td><td><input type="text" name="length'.$x.'" value="'.$row['length'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Inversions : </td><td><input type="text" name="inversions'.$x.'" value="'.$row['inversions'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>';
                } 

                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2)){ $xx++;
                echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row2['ride_id'].'" name="ride_id'.$xx.'">';
                    echo '<tr><td>Name : </td><td><input type="text" name="ride_name'.$xx.'" value="'.$row2['name'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Type : </td><td><input type="text" name="type'.$xx.'" value="'.$row2['type'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Top Ride : </td><td><input type="text" name="topride'.$xx.'" value="'.$row2['top_ride'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Info : </td><td><input type="text" name="info'.$xx.'" value="'.$row2['info'].'"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr>';
                }

                ?>
                    <tr><td>Password :</td><td><input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input onclick="return check()" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"></td></tr>

                </table>
               </form>
                <?php
            }else{
                echo "No Rides in this park.";
            }
    }else{
        if(isset($_GET['msg'])){echo $_GET['msg'].'<br>';}
        $qry = "select * from  tpf_parks order by name";
        $res = mysql_query($qry);
        ?>
        Select Park : <select name="park" onChange="getdata(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option value="">Select Park</option>
        <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
        <option value="<?=$row['park_id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></option>
        <?  } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

After testing what is not getting amended, it is data from both the LIKE and NOT LIKE queries being skipped so perhaps a record count problem?
Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: thats a lot of code, you need to narrow it down

Comment: yup and maybe you should consider refactoring your code a little bit ;)

Comment: I don't have time to go through the code, but if you've split into `LIKE` / `NOT LIKE` remember that both will return false if they're used with a null value. Try checking for nulls, for example: `... AND (type IS NULL OR type NOT LIKE '%Roller Coaster%')` - the parentheses are important here because of the `OR` don't leave them out. Or you could try `... AND COALESCE(type, 'X') NOT LIKE '%Roller Coaster%'`.

Comment: I only added the full script because I am a novice with this and I'm unsure as to which part is causing the update not to work with every record.

Comment: `error_log()` is a useful tool. Sprinkle it liberally throughout your code to get some idea about what is actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your column type has value 'Roller Coaster' or not?

Sorry to post as an answer as I have no rights no comment.

Comment: 'type' is the name of a column it's a varchar data type some strings contain 'Roller Coaster' others do not